# Exclude JPA 2.0 from JBoss 7.1 in order to use hibernate 4.3

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, jboss7.x, jpa-2.1

I want to use hibernate 4.3 for its multitenancy features in JBoss 7.1.

I managed to include it in my war by adding the following lines in jboss-deployment-structure

```
<exclusions>
   <module name="org.hibernate" />
</exclusions>
```

and adding a dependency to hibernate core and entity manager in my pom.xml

This made hibernate 4.3 to load but unfortunately I got an error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

which is due to JPA 2.0 being loaded when hibernate 4.3 is using JPA 2.1

I have seen these threads and tried what they suggest
[Excluding JPA Subsystem from JBoss EAP 6.1 - Trying to use JPA 2.1 in JBoss EAP 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078551/excluding-jpa-subsystem-from-jboss-eap-6-1-trying-to-use-jpa-2-1-in-jboss-eap), [JBoss AS7 Automatically Loading JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231575/jboss-as7-automatically-loading-jpa), [Hibernate 4.3.0.Final & Spring Data JPA 1.4.3.RELEASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157123/hibernate-4-3-0-final-spring-data-jpa-1-4-3-release).

I added a persistence.xml with

```
<property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false" />
```

excluded hibernate jpa 2.0 from Spring Data

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-data.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Removed JPA subsystem completely from JBoss standalone.xml, without any success.

The only thing that did the trick was to exclude the whole javaee.api in jboss-deployment-structure, as suggested in another thread

```
<exclusions>
    <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
    <module name="javaee.api"/>
</exclusions>
```

but this causes many problems to the rest of my code.

UPDATE: my jboss-deployment-structure.xml is now like this

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.slf4j" />
        <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
        <module name="org.hibernate" />
    </exclusions>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" />
        <module name="org.hornetq" />
        <module name="org.hornetq.ra" />
        <module name="org.jboss.ejb3" />
        <module name="org.jboss.ejb-client" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

As you see I have tried many things without luck, so if anyone has another idea it is most welcome.

Comment: In this thread it is discussed why this error is due to JPA 2.1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734540/nosuchmethoderror-in-javax-persistence-table-indexesljavax-persistence-index

Comment: try using mvn dependency:tree command and check what is being included

Comment: It might help to see the full stack trace and all of the dependencies with their actual versions.

Comment: Haven't found a solution yet. In case anyone is interested, moved to Wildfly and everything works fine.

Comment: After a lot of research and attempts this thread solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706871/using-jpa-2-1-in-eap-6-4-0/34047877#34047877

Answer (score 8):

I would split this problem into two smaller:

**1)** Make sure you're not transitively depending on JPA 2.0

For this you can use dependency graph visualization tool (NetBeans have one built in, or you can use a maven dependency tree plugin).
Another way would be just to skim through the libs, included in your artifact before deploying to JBoss.

**2)** Ensure correct configuration of JBoss AS 7.1

JBoss AS 7.1 is bundled with Hibernate 4.0.x jars, in order to update them try out this steps as described in the [official doc](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-ReplacingthecurrentHibernate4.0.xjarswithanewerversion).

- update the current `as7/modules/org/hibernate/main` folder to contain the newer version
- Delete *.index files in `as7/modules/org/hibernate/main` and `as7/modules/org/hibernate/envers/main` folders
- Backup the current contents of `as7/modules/org/hibernate` in case you make a mistake
- Remove the older jars and copy new Hibernate jars into `as7/modules/org/hibernate/main` + `as7/modules/org/hibernate/envers/main`
- Update the `as7/modules/org/hibernate/main/module.xml` + `as7/modules/org/hibernate/envers/main/module.xml` to name the jars that you copied in

Updated `as7/modules/org/hibernate/main/module.xml` will look like (note that dependencies won't change):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.hibernate">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-infinispan-4.3.5.Final.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
       .
       .
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: Have you successfully used something from hibernate 4.3 that uses JPA 2.1?
My project seems to have no dependency on JPA 2.0, and still JBoss 7.1 loads it. That is my problem, changing hibernate version is done correctly.

Comment: which version do you change to?

Comment: this **does not work for us: *JBoss 7.1.1.Final* and *Hibernate 4.3.7 Libs* since we get a **`NoClassDefFoundError` for `org/hibernate/service/jta/platform/internal/JBossAppServerJtaPlatform`** which was refactored to another place `org/hibernate/engine/transaction/jta/platform/internal`... http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-service-jta-platform-spi-jtaplatform/ (your link to the official site mentions JPA 2.0 compatiblity for JB7 and the hibernate upgrade procedure mentioned there is maybe only working for versions below 2.1 support).

Comment: I have found the reason for that error.  In standalone.xml, under the extensions tag, remove `<extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>` and the error will disappear. If that line is not removed, Jboss will attempt to load that extension, and if you check the corresponding module for that extension in the module folders, it uses a hibernate-4.0.* jar.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing only the `javax.persistence.api` module along with `org.hibernate`.

Also, if you want to switch to Hibernate 4.3 for all web applications (which should be backward compatible), switch to a newer version of Hibernate as described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-ReplacingthecurrentHibernate4.0.xjarswithanewerversion).

Some debugging tips: after generating your JAR files, check explicitly what JPA/Hibernate libraries they contain (by unzipping them). Also in order to check the Hibernate Version you could do it [like it is here described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480608/hibernate-version).

Also check the structure of the [jboss-deployment-structure file](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7#ClassLoadinginAS7-JBossDeploymentStructureFile), as it seems that the `<exclusions>` element is neither in a `<deployment>`, nor in an `<sub-deployment>` element.

Comment: removing the javax.persistence.api leads to the same error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

The method proposed to change the hibernate version, works up to the point where hibernate starts using JPA 2.1. Version 4.3 does so there is a conflict with JPA 2.0 that is enforced somehow by JBoss 7.1

Comment: Let's start debugging: Make the change I proposed to change the hibernate version and start your JBOSS with the JVM option: `-verbose:class`. You should get printed all loaded classes and the JARS where they have been taken from. Identify the `javax.persistence.Table` class please and print that line in a comment below.

Comment: Also make sure there is no wrong JARS with the JPA API, by executing `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: I haven't changed hibernate for the whole JBoss 7.1, but did only for my project. After starting jboss with -verbose:class, I can see that JPA 2.0 is loaded at the very start of my project deployment even before loading persistence.xml.
Then after some time this class is loaded:
[Loaded javax.persistence.Table from jar:file:jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/javax/persistence/api/main/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar!/]

Comment: 1. Why not changing Hibernate for the whole JBOSS 7.1? 2. Have you tried removing both dependencies `org.hibernate` and `javax.persistence.api`? 3. Show us the entire jboss-deployment-structure.xml file.

Comment: I will try changing the hibernate for the whole JBoss soon, I did before with no luck, since JBoss was complaining from the startup.
Both dependencies are now removed.
I updated the xml in my question.

Comment: Did you try changing it again?

Answer (score 0):

for us the following helped (**works only for non-container-managed JPA scenarios!**):

1. **IDE-side:** (Eclipse Kepler) removing (added during tests and forgot to remove) the **(locally installed) *JBoss 7.1.1.Final Library* project *Build Path* dependency**
2. **Maven-side:** (mvn 3.0.4 and 3.3.3) **outcommented** the following ***hibernate JPA 2.0 including*** section in our global **`/pom.xml`** (its an ear project with `/pom.xml`, `ear/pom.xml`, `ejb/pom.xml` and `web/pom.xml`:

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

       ...

       <dependencyManagement>
           <dependencies>
               ...

               <!-- outcommented because of JPA 2.1 support -->
               <!-- 
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
                   <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                   <type>pom</type>
                   <scope>import</scope>
               </dependency>
               -->
           </dependencies>
       </dependencyManagement>

       ...
   ```
3. **Maven-side:** **adding only *hibernate-entitymanager 4.3.8.Final* and our db driver (postgres) as DB/ORM-related dependencies** (which load all other required libs as well) in our **`/ejb/pom.xml`**

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
       <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
       <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
4. **server-side:** **disabling JPA 2.0 in our JBoss 7.1.1.Final globally** (for all webapps/libs, if you have multiple) setting **`<module name="javax.persistence.api" export="false"/>`**

   - in `jboss-as/modules/javaee/api/main/module.xml` as suggested here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-209?_sscc=t

hints:

- the (also tried) **`/ear/src/main/application/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` portable solution cannot work with JBoss 7.1.1.Final** since the `<exclude-subsystem>` feature was added in *JBoss 7.1.2* later, see

  - suggestion to do this: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-209?_sscc=t
  - *Workaround 2* will cause XML Parse/Namespace Exceptions:

    - https://developer.jboss.org/message/784133?_sscc=t#784133
    - https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7?focusedCommentId=53379592&_sscc=t#comment-53379592
    - [Jboss AS7 - jboss-deployment-structure.xml deployment error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995263/jboss-as7-jboss-deployment-structure-xml-deployment-error#comment48794164_15008274)
    - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/258543
    - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=953328

Answer (score -2):

try using a lower version of the hibernate-entitymanager

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and jpa 2.0 may work > It worked for me.