# Using JPA 2.1 in EAP 6.4.0

Tags: jpa, jboss, classpath, classloader

I searched for a solution for this problem without having success so far.

We're migrating our aplications over to EAP 6.4.0, and our applications relies on JPA 2.1.  However, JBoss is a Java EE 6 server, and therefore includes JPA 2.0 in the form of a module.

I tried including the JPA API jar directly in my WEB-INF/lib directory, thinking the classloader would prefer this one over the one from the system.

I have tried to include a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file in my ear.  I tried it under ear/META-INF, ear/war/META-INF, and ear/war/WEB-INF.

In the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file, I tried to:
exclude the javax.persistence.api module
create my own module with JPA 2.1 and add a dependency to it
exclude the jpa subsystem

I also tried to set the export attribute to false in the javax.persistence.api module.xml file located under jboss-eap-6.4.0\modules\system\layers\base\javax\persistence\api\main

I tried removing the jpa subsystem from the standalone.xml.

All of these things resulted in the JPA 2.0 jar being used.

The only way I got it to work was to replace the actual jar in the module directory (jboss-eap-6.4.0\modules\system\layers\base\javax\persistence\api\main).  But that's not a valid solution as other apps or services in the server may actually need the old version of the API.

Is there a way to do this correctly (without migrating to another server nor changing the code)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please take a look at:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-209

This is a copy from the link above:

**workaround 1**

update the javaee/api/main.module.xml as followed:

```
<!--<module name="javax.persistence.api" export="true"/>-->
```

though this is non-portable.

**workaround 2**

update jboss-deployment-structure.xml as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jpa" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- WFCORE-209 workaround -->
            <module name="javaee.api" />
            <!-- --------------------- -->
            <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
            <module name="org.hibernate" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- WFCORE-209 workaround -->
            <module name="javax.activation.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.annotation.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.ejb.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.el.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.enterprise.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.enterprise.deploy.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.inject.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.interceptor.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.jms.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.jws.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.mail.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.management.j2ee.api" export="true"/>
            <!-- <module name="javax.persistence.api" export="true"/> -->
            <module name="javax.resource.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.rmi.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.security.auth.message.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.security.jacc.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.servlet.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.transaction.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.validation.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" export="true"  services="export"/>
            <module name="javax.xml.bind.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.xml.registry.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.xml.soap.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.xml.ws.api" export="true"/>

            <!-- This one always goes last. -->
            <module name="javax.api" export="true"/>
            <!-- --------------------- -->
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

this is fully portable

Comment: I am getting this error [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V