# JPA error using JBoss AS 7.1 and Hibernate 4.3.8.Final

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I'm trying to implement Hibernate annotated mapping using javax.persistence annotations, Hibernate version 4.3.8.Final and Spring version 4.1.5.RELEASE. Hibernate configuration bean is in XML configuration file. Portlet is deployed on JBoss AS 7.1.

Mapping using hbm.xml works fine.

The same annotated mapping works fine using Java 8 and Tomcat 9.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code and error.

```
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Table(name="DATABASE_NAME.dbo.TEST_TABLE")
@Entity(name="TestTable")
public class TestTable implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2684585650977133637L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="TEXT_COLUMN")
    private String textColumn;

    public TestTable() {}

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTextColumn() {
        return textColumn;
    }

    public void setTextColumn(String textColumn) {
        this.textColumn = textColumn;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestTable [id=" + id + ", textColumn=" + textColumn + "]";
    }

}
```

bean configuration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>test.TestTable</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

error log:

```
10:03:28,276 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/BasicData-portlet]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) StandardWrapper.Throwable: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) [spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.instantiatingListener(SecurePluginContextListener.java:360) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.instantiatingListeners(SecurePluginContextListener.java:163) [portal-service.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.java:77)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.java:37)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:230)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:28) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:164) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:154) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:44) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:74) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:58) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:54) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:116) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.contextInitialized(SecurePluginContextListener.java:151) [portal-service.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:973) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:824) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372) [spring-orm-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454) [spring-orm-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439) [spring-orm-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 39 more

10:03:28,300 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/BasicData-portlet].[springServlet]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Allocate exception for servlet springServlet: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:973) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:824) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372) [spring-orm-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454) [spring-orm-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439) [spring-orm-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) [spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.instantiatingListener(SecurePluginContextListener.java:360) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.instantiatingListeners(SecurePluginContextListener.java:163) [portal-service.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.java:77)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.java:37)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:230)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:28) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:164) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:154) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:44) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:74) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:58) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:54) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:116) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.contextInitialized(SecurePluginContextListener.java:151) [portal-service.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

Comment: java 8? Error log says 1.7.0_79

Comment: Wonder what happens when you put that exception in the SEARCH BAR above ? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.lang.NoSuchMethodError%3A+javax.persistence.Table.indexes%28%29%5BLjavax%2Fpersistence%2FIndex%3B

Comment: @bejond here with JBoss I use Java 7 but on Tomcat 9 I use Java 8

Comment: this would solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734540/nosuchmethoderror-in-javax-persistence-table-indexesljavax-persistence-index

Comment: @bejond I tried to exclude module javax.persistence in jboss-deployment-structure.xml and add maven dependency <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>  but it does not work

Comment: @DN1 everything I found on Stackoverflow search bar does not work

Comment: everything on the search bar points to the SAME THING. You have a more recent version of javax.persistence.jar (JPA 2.1/2.2) in your CLASSPATH somewhere (whilst your JPA provider is for JPA 2.0). That's all it can be.

Comment: @DN1 is it possible if some other project which is in Maven pom.xml file like dependency of that project have some other JPA version (or that version) and it is a problem? I deleted the older version of JPA from Maven .m2 folder. I have Maven multi module project.

Comment: Check the dependencies using `mvn dependency:tree` and add an exclusion to that dependency that causes the import of the more recent version of javax.persistence.jar as @DN1 pointed out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294492/exclude-jpa-2-0-from-jboss-7-1-in-order-to-use-hibernate-4-3

Comment: @Sal I excluded hibernate-jpa-2.1-api from hibernate-entitymanager 4.3.8.Final and I excluded javaee.api in jboss-deployment-structure.xml but there is the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that works:

I put in JBoss module folder (boss-7.1.1\modules\javax\persistence\api\main) the same JAR that is inside of Hibernate core dependency in Maven pom.xml file and I changed resource-root of module.xml to point on that dependency.

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="javax.persistence.api">
    <dependencies>
        <!-- PersistenceUnitInfo needs javax.sql.DataSource -->
        <module name="javax.api" export="true"/>
    </dependencies>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>
</module>
```